# Cordova native calls not working when deploying meteor on my own server

Tags: mongodb, cordova, meteor, meteorite

I have my meteor app with cordova running fine on meteor.com. However when I run it on my own server, the native calls fail to work. Any idea on the correct ENV variables in order for it to work fine?

http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Environment_Variables#Environment

Edited: As requested, I'll be more clear.

1. I create a "Hello world" meteor app and deploy it to myapp.meteor.com
2. Using MeteorRider I integrate it with Cordova/Phonegap
3. I add a native plug-in to cordova, let's say org.apache.cordova.vibration
4. I call it from Meteor "navigator.notification.vibrate();"
5. I load it on my iPhone. Everything works as expected.

Now I want to run meteor on my own server. I create a meteor bundle, unpack it and run it with this sh:

```
#/bin/sh
cd /root
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/wc
export PORT=3000
export ROOT_URL=http://123.456.789.000:3000/
#export METEOR_SETTINGS=$(<settings.json)
forever start bundle/main.js
```

I change the meteor url to my ROOT_URL and everything works except the native calls. ie navigator.notification.vibrate() fails

Comment: You need to post more information on the configuration of your project and deployment in your question in order for someone to answer or even be considered on topic. Please do so.

Comment: I think there are some meteor plugin install stages you are missing her and also likely from your new deployment. Not enough information, if the comments were not enough of a hint.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer myself. I am posting this here as it might help others. This is what I was using on my index.html to configure MeteorRider.

Everything works, except plug-in calls:

```
var __MeteorRiderConfig__ = {
            meteorUrl:  "http://123.456.789.000:3000/",
            phonegapVersion: 3.3,
            phonegapAppVersion: 1.01
        };
```

Everything works, *including* plug-in native calls:

```
var __MeteorRiderConfig__ = {
            meteorUrl:  "http://123.456.789.000:3000",
            phonegapVersion: 3.3,
            phonegapAppVersion: 1.01
        };
```

Notice the difference? Yeah, right :)